# Magento2: Updating products with CSV duplicates product_id in cataloginventory_stock_item

Tags: magento2, import, csv, cataloginventory

Any ideas why Magento 2 creates duplicate **product_id** into `cataloginventory_stock_item` table for each product that I try to update via **import** functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like bug. Can you create issue in github?